# Executing a Python file with Ajax

Tags: python, html, ajax

I am trying to run a python script on page load. The python script will save a log.text file with some log information. After doing some research I came up with:

```
    <script>
    window.onload = function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "img/test.py",
            success: function () {
                alert("working")
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Not Working")
            }
        });
    };
</script>
```

Which works, everytime the page loads it alerts me that it was successful. And here is test.py:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/env python

try:
    txt = open(r'log.txt', "wb")
    txt.write("Success")
    txt.close()
except Exception,e:
    txt = open(r'log.txt', "wb")
    txt.write(e)
    txt.close()
```

But this is where the problem is. The file is not created and I don't know why.

More information:
I am using godaddy as a hosting service. My script is written in python2.6. 
When I ssh in and use:

```
$ python path_to_file/test.py
```

It creates the file in the current cd location. So the server can run the file with python but when i use:

```
$ cd path_to_file
$ ./test.py
```

I get:

```
-bash: ./test.py: Permission denied
```

Is that a problem or is this normal? Everything else works I just seem to be missing one piece of this puzzle. Is my shebang statement correct? Why does my process not generate a log.txt file?

Comment: Aren't you just reading the contents of the python script via ajax? If you change `success: function () { alert("working") }` to `success: function (data) { alert(data) }` and see the python code, it's not being executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you set the execution flag on that file?

```
  chmod +x test.py
```

should do…